# PHP Date Issue or Bug d/m/Y format - date ends up 1970-01-01

Tags: php, date, strtotime

Why does the following dates (Regardless of the year) give **1970-01-01** when using the following code :
`echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime('25/12/2000'))`.
**PHP Version 7.0.21**

`Array
(
    [0] => 13/01/2000
    [1] => 14/01/2000
    [2] => 15/01/2000
    [3] => 16/01/2000
    [4] => 17/01/2000
    [5] => 18/01/2000
    [6] => 19/01/2000
    [7] => 20/01/2000
    [8] => 21/01/2000
    [9] => 22/01/2000
    [10] => 23/01/2000
    [11] => 24/01/2000
    [12] => 25/01/2000
    [13] => 26/01/2000
    [14] => 27/01/2000
    [15] => 28/01/2000
    [16] => 29/01/2000
    [17] => 30/01/2000
    [18] => 31/01/2000
    [19] => 13/02/2000
    [20] => 14/02/2000
    [21] => 15/02/2000
    [22] => 16/02/2000
    [23] => 17/02/2000
    [24] => 18/02/2000
    [25] => 19/02/2000
    [26] => 20/02/2000
    [27] => 21/02/2000
    [28] => 22/02/2000
    [29] => 23/02/2000
    [30] => 24/02/2000
    [31] => 25/02/2000
    [32] => 26/02/2000
    [33] => 27/02/2000
    [34] => 28/02/2000
    [35] => 29/02/2000
    [36] => 30/02/2000
    [37] => 31/02/2000
    [38] => 13/03/2000
    [39] => 14/03/2000
    [40] => 15/03/2000
    [41] => 16/03/2000
    [42] => 17/03/2000
    [43] => 18/03/2000
    [44] => 19/03/2000
    [45] => 20/03/2000
    [46] => 21/03/2000
    [47] => 22/03/2000
    [48] => 23/03/2000
    [49] => 24/03/2000
    [50] => 25/03/2000
    [51] => 26/03/2000
    [52] => 27/03/2000
    [53] => 28/03/2000
    [54] => 29/03/2000
    [55] => 30/03/2000
    [56] => 31/03/2000
    [57] => 13/04/2000
    [58] => 14/04/2000
    [59] => 15/04/2000
    [60] => 16/04/2000
    [61] => 17/04/2000
    [62] => 18/04/2000
    [63] => 19/04/2000
    [64] => 20/04/2000
    [65] => 21/04/2000
    [66] => 22/04/2000
    [67] => 23/04/2000
    [68] => 24/04/2000
    [69] => 25/04/2000
    [70] => 26/04/2000
    [71] => 27/04/2000
    [72] => 28/04/2000
    [73] => 29/04/2000
    [74] => 30/04/2000
    [75] => 31/04/2000
    [76] => 13/05/2000
    [77] => 14/05/2000
    [78] => 15/05/2000
    [79] => 16/05/2000
    [80] => 17/05/2000
    [81] => 18/05/2000
    [82] => 19/05/2000
    [83] => 20/05/2000
    [84] => 21/05/2000
    [85] => 22/05/2000
    [86] => 23/05/2000
    [87] => 24/05/2000
    [88] => 25/05/2000
    [89] => 26/05/2000
    [90] => 27/05/2000
    [91] => 28/05/2000
    [92] => 29/05/2000
    [93] => 30/05/2000
    [94] => 31/05/2000
    [95] => 13/06/2000
    [96] => 14/06/2000
    [97] => 15/06/2000
    [98] => 16/06/2000
    [99] => 17/06/2000
    [100] => 18/06/2000
    [101] => 19/06/2000
    [102] => 20/06/2000
    [103] => 21/06/2000
    [104] => 22/06/2000
    [105] => 23/06/2000
    [106] => 24/06/2000
    [107] => 25/06/2000
    [108] => 26/06/2000
    [109] => 27/06/2000
    [110] => 28/06/2000
    [111] => 29/06/2000
    [112] => 30/06/2000
    [113] => 31/06/2000
    [114] => 13/07/2000
    [115] => 14/07/2000
    [116] => 15/07/2000
    [117] => 16/07/2000
    [118] => 17/07/2000
    [119] => 18/07/2000
    [120] => 19/07/2000
    [121] => 20/07/2000
    [122] => 21/07/2000
    [123] => 22/07/2000
    [124] => 23/07/2000
    [125] => 24/07/2000
    [126] => 25/07/2000
    [127] => 26/07/2000
    [128] => 27/07/2000
    [129] => 28/07/2000
    [130] => 29/07/2000
    [131] => 30/07/2000
    [132] => 31/07/2000
    [133] => 13/08/2000
    [134] => 14/08/2000
    [135] => 15/08/2000
    [136] => 16/08/2000
    [137] => 17/08/2000
    [138] => 18/08/2000
    [139] => 19/08/2000
    [140] => 20/08/2000
    [141] => 21/08/2000
    [142] => 22/08/2000
    [143] => 23/08/2000
    [144] => 24/08/2000
    [145] => 25/08/2000
    [146] => 26/08/2000
    [147] => 27/08/2000
    [148] => 28/08/2000
    [149] => 29/08/2000
    [150] => 30/08/2000
    [151] => 31/08/2000
    [152] => 13/09/2000
    [153] => 14/09/2000
    [154] => 15/09/2000
    [155] => 16/09/2000
    [156] => 17/09/2000
    [157] => 18/09/2000
    [158] => 19/09/2000
    [159] => 20/09/2000
    [160] => 21/09/2000
    [161] => 22/09/2000
    [162] => 23/09/2000
    [163] => 24/09/2000
    [164] => 25/09/2000
    [165] => 26/09/2000
    [166] => 27/09/2000
    [167] => 28/09/2000
    [168] => 29/09/2000
    [169] => 30/09/2000
    [170] => 31/09/2000
    [171] => 13/10/2000
    [172] => 14/10/2000
    [173] => 15/10/2000
    [174] => 16/10/2000
    [175] => 17/10/2000
    [176] => 18/10/2000
    [177] => 19/10/2000
    [178] => 20/10/2000
    [179] => 21/10/2000
    [180] => 22/10/2000
    [181] => 23/10/2000
    [182] => 24/10/2000
    [183] => 25/10/2000
    [184] => 26/10/2000
    [185] => 27/10/2000
    [186] => 28/10/2000
    [187] => 29/10/2000
    [188] => 30/10/2000
    [189] => 31/10/2000
    [190] => 13/11/2000
    [191] => 14/11/2000
    [192] => 15/11/2000
    [193] => 16/11/2000
    [194] => 17/11/2000
    [195] => 18/11/2000
    [196] => 19/11/2000
    [197] => 20/11/2000
    [198] => 21/11/2000
    [199] => 22/11/2000
    [200] => 23/11/2000
    [201] => 24/11/2000
    [202] => 25/11/2000
    [203] => 26/11/2000
    [204] => 27/11/2000
    [205] => 28/11/2000
    [206] => 29/11/2000
    [207] => 30/11/2000
    [208] => 31/11/2000
    [209] => 13/12/2000
    [210] => 14/12/2000
    [211] => 15/12/2000
    [212] => 16/12/2000
    [213] => 17/12/2000
    [214] => 18/12/2000
    [215] => 19/12/2000
    [216] => 20/12/2000
    [217] => 21/12/2000
    [218] => 22/12/2000
    [219] => 23/12/2000
    [220] => 24/12/2000
    [221] => 25/12/2000
    [222] => 26/12/2000
    [223] => 27/12/2000
    [224] => 28/12/2000
    [225] => 29/12/2000
    [226] => 30/12/2000
    [227] => 31/12/2000
)`

Comment: Because `strtotime()` tries to do magic, and magic is bad.

Comment: Read about the [date and time formats](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php) recognized by [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php). `d/m/Y` is not between them. It clashes with `m/d/Y` and `m/d/Y` was chosen.

Comment: @Hanky panky What Should i do? Remove This

Answer (score 2):

strtotime does not accept the format you are providing it with
Use DateTime, which is intended for this

```
$dt = new \DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y','25/12/2000');
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: Should have marked your answer as right. But question is marked as duplicate.

Comment: I'll learn to live with it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try using '-' instead of '/'

31/12/2000 to 31-12-2000